# oracle auto increment missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table grocery_types(

    type_id int auto_increment primary key,
    grocery_type varchar(50) not null,
    remarks varchar(30)

);
```

I am using oracle sql developer IDE for sql queries, i am executing this query in my IDE but its giving an error that "missing right parenthesis", and in IDE there is a red line under the auto_increment keyword, please tell me whats wrong in the code, thanks.

Comment: If this is about 12c, it's easy: `type_id      NUMBER        GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY`.

Comment: Where in the [Oracle manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/toc.htm) did you find `auto_increment`?

Answer (score 3):

I think there isn't a way to use auto_increment if yours is 11g.

But you can use a sequence :

```
  create table grocery_types(

        type_id int primary key,
        grocery_type varchar(50) not null,
        remarks varchar(30)

    );

CREATE SEQUENCE type_id_seq START WITH 1;
```

Comment: And a trigger to set the value.